# Angular 2 Datalist Option click event in Angular 2

Tags: html, typescript, angular, angular2-forms, html-datalist

I am having Html 5 datalist control in my angular 2 application i want to fire click event on datalist option and execute my angular method on option click.
i am able to archive this on change event of text box but not able to do the same on datalist option click.
I don't want to use jquery but only Angular 2 and typescript.

```
<div class="paddingBottem20">
                        <label> Search Model ID</label>
                        <input type="text" (keyup)="getModelId(cSetDetail.ModelDescriptionWithID)" 
[(ngModel)]="cSetDetail.ModelDescriptionWithID" class="form-control" list="lstModels"  placeholder="Search Model Id">
<datalist id="lstModels">
<option [value]="'ModelID ' + ' ModelDescription'"></option>
<option *ngFor="let item of lstModels" [value]="item.ModelID + '--' + item.ModelDescription" ></option>
</datalist>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Nishant Kumar

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: (click)="addModelToChangeSet(changesetDetail[0].Title)"  on datalist option not working while change event on text box is working.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.